# How to Refactor a Unity PoolManager Class for Generic Object Pooling?

Tags: unity, c#, object-pools

I'd like to refactor my pooling class to work for more object types in my top down Unity game. Right now it's working fine for player projectiles, but I want it to also work for enemy projectiles, enemies, particle effects, basically anything that may spawn and be destroyed. I also feel that it's rather clunky to assign the `projectilePrefab` directly in the manager, so I was also wondering if something like an `Interface` like `IPoolable` would be the way to go.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Pool;

public class PoolManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Pooled Objects

    [SerializeField] private Projectile _projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField] private Enemy _enemyPrefab;

    private ObjectPool<Projectile> _projectilePool;
    private ObjectPool<Enemy> _enemyPool;

    #endregion

    [SerializeField] private int _projectilePoolAmount;
    [SerializeField] private bool _usePool = true;

    public static PoolManager Instance { get; private set; }
    private GameObject _poolContainer;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;

        _poolContainer = new GameObject($"PoolContainer - {_projectilePrefab.name}");
        _poolContainer.transform.SetParent(transform);

        InitializeProjectilePool();
    }

    private void InitializeProjectilePool()
    {
        _projectilePool = new ObjectPool<Projectile>(
            CreateProjectile,
            projectile => {
                projectile.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }, projectile => {
                projectile.gameObject.SetActive(false); 
            }, projectile => {
                Destroy(projectile.gameObject); 
            }, false, 10, 200);
    }

    private Projectile CreateProjectile()
    {
        Projectile projectileInstance = Instantiate(_projectilePrefab);
        projectileInstance.transform.SetParent(_poolContainer.transform);
        projectileInstance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        return projectileInstance;
    }
    private void KillProjectile(Projectile projectile)
    {
        if (_usePool) { _projectilePool.Release(projectile); }
        else { Destroy(projectile.gameObject); }
    }

    public Projectile GetProjectile()
    {
        var projectile = _usePool ? _projectilePool.Get() : CreateProjectile();
        projectile.Init(KillProjectile);
        return projectile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a separate manager for each type of prefab, you can make PoolManager an abstract generic class and then add concrete implementations. Here's an abbreviated example; for brevity, I won't rewrite the entire class (`// [...]` indicates where code has been omitted):

```
public class PoolManager<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Component
{
    [SerializeField] private T _prefab;
    [SerializeField] private int _poolAmount;
    [SerializeField] private bool _usePool = true;

    private ObjectPool<T> pool;

    // [...]

    private T CreateInstance()
    {
        T instance = Instantiate(_prefab);
        instance .transform.SetParent(_poolContainer.transform);
        instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        return instance;
    }
    
    // [...]
}

public class ProjectilePoolManager : PoolManager<Projectile> {
    // This concrete implementation doesn't need any additional code!
}

public class EnemyPoolManager : PoolManager<Enemy> {
    // This concrete implementation doesn't need any additional code!
}
```

This is the approach I typically use.

If you want one pool manager component to manage *all* of your pools, rather than having a separate pool manager for each type of pool, that gets more complicated. It would look something like this:

```
public class PoolManager : MonoBehaviour {
    // Note that because `ObjectPool<T>` is a generic type, we can't use `ObjectPool<T>` 
    // as the value type of the dictionary, so we cast to `object`.
    private Dictionary<Type, object> _pools;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> pools {
        get {
            if (_pools == null) _pools = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
            return _pools;
        }
    }

    public void CreatePool<T>(T prefab, Transform parent) where T : Component {
        var pool = new ObjectPool<T>(
            () => CreateInstance<T>(prefab, parent),
            instance => {
                instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }, instance => {
                instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }, instance => {
                Destroy(instance.gameObject);
            }, false, 10, 200);
        pools.Add(typeof(T), pool);
    }

    private ObjectPool<T> GetPool<T>() where T : Component {
        if (pools.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var poolObj)) {
            var pool = poolObj as ObjectPool<T>;
            return pool;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public T GetInstance<T>() where T : Component {
        var pool = GetPool<T>();
        if (pool == null) return null;
        return pool.Get();
    }

    public void Release<T>(T instance) where T : Component {
        var pool = GetPool<T>();
        if (pool == null) Debug.LogWarning($"Tried to release {instance}, but there's no pool of type {typeof(T).Name}");
        else pool.Release(instance);
    }

    private T CreateInstance<T>(T prefab, Transform parent) where T : Component {
        T instance = Instantiate(prefab);
        instance.transform.SetParent(parent);
        instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This component lets you create a separate object pool for each type of prefab you want to spawn. However, take note that this particular implementation I just threw together only lets you have one spawn pool per type, which doesn't work if you have multiple prefabs with the same component type (e.g. multiple prefabs of type `Enemy`).

---

And, at the risk of going overboard on this answer, here's an implementation where pools are mapped by prefab, so you can have different pools for different prefabs with the same type:

```
public class PoolManager : MonoBehaviour {
    // Note that because `ObjectPool<T>` is a generic type, we can't use `ObjectPool<T>` 
    // as the value type of the dictionary, so we cast to `object`.
    private Dictionary<Component, object> _pools;
    private Dictionary<Component, object> pools {
        get {
            if (_pools == null) _pools = new Dictionary<Component, object>();
            return _pools;
        }
    }

    public ObjectPool<T> CreatePool<T>(T prefab) where T : Component {
        var pool = new ObjectPool<T>(
            () => CreateInstance<T>(prefab),
            instance => {
                instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }, instance => {
                instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }, instance => {
                Destroy(instance.gameObject);
            }, false, 10, 200);
        pools.Add(prefab, pool);
        return pool;
    }

    private ObjectPool<T> GetPool<T>(T prefab) where T : Component {
        if (pools.TryGetValue(prefab, out var poolObj)) {
            var pool = poolObj as ObjectPool<T>;
            return pool;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public T GetInstance<T>(T prefab, Transform parent) where T : Component {
        var pool = GetPool<T>(prefab);
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = CreatePool<T>(prefab);
        }
        var instance = pool.Get();
        if (instance != null) instance.transform.SetParent(parent);
        return instance;
    }

    public void Release<T>(T prefab, T instance) where T : Component {
        var pool = GetPool<T>(prefab);
        if (pool == null) Debug.LogWarning($"Tried to release {instance}, but there's no pool of type {typeof(T).Name}");
        else pool.Release(instance);
    }

    private T CreateInstance<T>(T prefab) where T : Component {
        T instance = Instantiate(prefab);
        instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        return instance;
    }
}
```